# React - How to reference reponse.data state?

Tags: reactjs, axios, frontend

New to React, having trouble understanding how to reference object data from response.data. Consider the following code:

```
import React, {useRef, useState, useEffect} from "react";
import UserService from "../services/user.service";
import AuthService from "../services/auth.service";
   
export const getUser = () => {
    
    // Retrieve user info from locally stored JSON
    const currentUser = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
    const [user, setUser] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        getUser();
    }, []);

    const getUser = () => {

        // Retrieve user info from DB using user id
        UserService.getUser(currentUser.id)
            .then(response => {
                setUser(response.data); // This is what I what I want to reference
                console.log(response.data);
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    };

    return (
        <div>
          {user.username}
        </div>
    );
};
```

I see the data properly returned in the console: {username: 'GlennQuagmire'}

And using debug tools in Webstorm, I see that user is being loaded with this value. But once we get to rendering {user.username}, nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the code, I used public API as a database but you can relate it to your code. I think you need to use `response.json()` and then set `data`. Also as you are setting the user as an object, the initial `useState` should be declared as an empty object `const [user, setUser] = useState({});`.

```js
const {useEffect, useState} = React;

const App = () => {
    //const currentUser = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
    const [user, setUser] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        getUser();
    }, []);

    const getUser = () => {
    // Retrieve user info from DB using user id
    fetch('https://api.agify.io/?name=Glenn Quagmire')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setUser(data);
        console.log(data)
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    };

    return (
        <div>
          {user.name}
        </div>
    );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, modeled in the return block:

```
    return (
        <div>
          {user && user.map((user, index) => (  
            <h1>{user.username}</h1>
          ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Seems like a roundabout way to get a single piece of data in there, but it works. If anyone has better suggestions, feel free to share.

Comment: You said you are getting an object `{username: 'GlennQuagmire'}`, but if you can `map` over the `user` object it means it's an array, not an object. I'm happy you solved the problem ^~^